# Weighted A* on wikipedia

Tags: algorithm, a-star

I guess I find a problem on this wiki [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm):

I think the `

> have a cost of at most ε times

in the **Weighted A* algorithm** part should be

> have a cost less than ε times

instead.

Because here it assumes ε > 1. But I am not sure about it, just want to listen anybody's opinion on this..

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Comment: @pnuts Not the most descriptive reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the paragraph starting "Weighted A*. If ha(n) is" is correct, and a guarantee that the cost of the path found is at most eta times the cost of the best path is the sort of guarantee you want - since you are looking for the least cost path and trying to reduce cpu time you are settling for a sub-optimal (higher cost) solution but obtaining a guarantee that the cost is not too bad - at most eta times the cost of the best path.

I do think that there is an inconsistency between the use of eta in this paragraph and that in the paragraph above - I don't know whether that is a mistake or whether it derives from an unfortunate difference of conventions between weighted A* and a more general definition of approximate solutions.

The paragraph is consistent with the notes at http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs188/sp11/slides/SP11%20cs188%20lecture%204%20--%20CSPs%206PP.pdf - bottom of page 5 on the pdf and with a rough proof. When weighted A* thinks it has a solution with cost g(x) all nodes still in play must have a predicted cost g(y) + eh(y) at least this. To get the largest possible error assume that g(y) is zero and that eh(y) = g(x) for correct solution y and we see that the solution A* thinks it has found is e times as expensive as y - since we presume that the original h() is admissable and therefore an upper bound on cost.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. Actually I am trying to prove that conclusion:
At the time goal_node is chosen, if current g(goal_node) is not optimal, there must be a node 'm' of the optimal path that is on the open-set(frontier), such that:
g(goal_node)+ωh(goal_node)=g(goal_node)+0 ≤ g(m)+ωh(m)<ω(g(m)+h(m))
Because h is always not overestimate, 
ω(g(m)+h(m))≤ω(g(m)+h′(m))=ω*c
So we get g(goal_node) < ω*c
As you can see, I can only prove a strict equal because ω(g(m)+h(m)) should be larger than g(m)+ωh(m) (will not be equal), given ω strictly greater than 1.

Comment: w(g(m)+h(m)) = g(m) + wh(m) if w>1 exactly when g(m) = 0, which is possible, if m is the source, or if the cost of routes from the source to m is zero.

Comment: Your original comment was that perhaps an upper bound should be a lower bound. I note that on some graphs even bad algorithms may return the correct answer - for example a graph with one edge linking the source and the destination and no other possible edges or routes.

Comment: But here is a rather interesting thing. At the time goal_node is chosen, if current g(goal_node) is not optimal, I think the optimal path must traverse through at least one unexplored node(because g(goal_node) now is guaranteed to be the optimum among explored set). Therefore m should not be the source simply because m will be put on explored list just after the first iteration of A algorithm if it is the source.

Comment: But I think your point makes sense in terms of that if the cost from source to m is zero. But to consider the graph should have every edge-cost exceeding some small positive constant ε to guarantee the completeness of search algorithm so that the search will not get stuck in an infinite loop if there is a path with an infinite sequence of zero-cost edges. Hence it seems the graph for A search algorithm should be without zero-cost edge.. and if this is the case, I think g(m)+ωh(m) should be less than ω(g(m)+h(m)) strictly.

Comment: I have tried to work through the Wikipedia algorithm with a triangle graph where one side is length zero. I think that it will not get stuck in an infinite loop because a node only returns to the open set if its tentative score decreases. I notice that in order to get a wrong answer with w times the correct cost I must assume that when it selects the node in the open set with lowest f score it breaks a tie in the wrong way so if you want to ensure < w instead of <= w you might be able to do so by changing the behaviour when there are many lowest f scores.

Comment: Now, I believe that, when the path found by the search algorithm can have a cost exactly ε times that of the least cost path in the graph, it must be the case that some edge-cost has a zero cost. Therefore I think, Wikipedia is implicitly assume the graph may contain zero-cost edge.

Comment: However, in contrast with you, I should argue the algorithm does has the possibility to get stuck in an infinite loop if there are some 'circle' with zero-cost and zero h function. So I conclude under the definition of Wikipedia's, the completeness of search algorithm will not be guaranteed.

Comment: In an infinite execution, at least one node is removed from the open set infinitely often. So it must be added in to the open set infinitely often, so the tentative_f_score must be reduced infinitely often, each less than the last, which I think can only happen if there are -ve cost cycles, which we can hopefully agree is a known problem. With only values >=0 there can only be a finite number of different values produced by adding them that are smaller than a previously agreed bound, because each non-zero value can only appear a finite number of times.

Comment: em.. I think you are right. Once a node was expanded, it was put on closed set. Next time a new node will be expanded which should not be on closed set. The path found by the search algorithm can have a cost ε times that of the least cost path in the graph when some path is zero-cost. Thank you!